# can't add padding to nested anchor tags in footer

Tags: html, css, sass

Trying to add a padding to my anchors in my footer and my sass keep erroring out saying:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS: a space is required between a property and its definition
              when it has other properties nested beneath it.
        on line 26 of /Users/Jarg/Desktop/web/omegascss/scss/app.scss

21:   margin-bottom: 3rem;
22: }
23: .footerlinks {
24:   position:relative;
25:   top:1.5em
26:   a {
27:    padding: 10px;
28:   }
29:   
30: }
31: .container{
```

html:

```
   <footer>
    <div class="row footerlinks">
      <div class="large-6">
        <a href="services.html#printing">Print Media</a>
        <a href="services.html">Web Development</a>
        <a href="services.html">Promotional Items</a></div>
      </div>
    <div class="large-6">

    </div>


    </footer>
```

No idea why. I dont see anything wrong with my syntax.

Comment: Unlike what @NiMa said, you can use a anchor tag inside a class. The reason your code doesn't work is because you forgot the `;` behind `top:1.5em`. And the reason why @NiMa answer works is because he closes the selector after `top: 1.5em` and repeats it with the anchor tag, which you shouldn't do when you're using Sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess it solves the problem

```
margin-bottom: 3rem;
     }
     .footerlinks {
       position:relative;
       top:1.5em;
       }
     .footerlinks a
     {
    padding: 10px;
    }
     .container{
```

Comment: yes that works, but i was really hoping for a scss answer as I dont understand why the original doesnt work, can someone explain that please?

Comment: actually you can't use anchor tag inside a class

Comment: @Jarg7 dear sir,its said up vote the question if "This question shows research effort..." please let me to do not up vote it,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to close the declaration on line 25 with a semicolon.

```
25:   top:1.5em;
```